# Would these centaurs be able to copulate with their human genitals?

Tags: internal-consistency, sex, centaur

The centaurs externally appears very human-like. They have human-like hips with regular genitalia in their natural place. The horse body is similarly sized to the human body, and is connected horizontally so that the lowest part of the chest is contiguous with the region between the forelegs. The horse body appears to connect at the front of the chest, with no shoulders. The human body can bend roughly as much as a regular human relative to the pelvis, and the pelvis can move about as much as a horse's humeri relative to the horse body. Besides this all of their parts can move and bend as in a human/horse

Based on their body structure and ability to bend and position themselves, would these centaurs be able to mate with each-other using their human genitalia?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: This seems like something that without a highly specific description of the exact structures involved and their placement this question is going to be impossible to meaningfully answer, with that information it should be trivial for you to figure out on your own. I'm unsure why you're asking us for help with this, especially since the bits involved and the human-part/horse-part interface are underdefined. VTC needs detail and clarity. Please remember that we're a roughly PG-13 site, getting too detailed with human genitals and copulation is crossing that line.

Comment: <h2>Yes</h2> If you didn't already know that, you're too young to legally use Stack Exchange. If you're expecting an explanation of how (a) I have no desire to tempt our Stack Exchange overlords' wrath and (b) writing your story is off-topic storybuilding.

Comment: The Q needs detail & clarity, but I think we can all agree it is *not* wanted.

Comment: I can't help but worry about those poor centaurs with human hips supporting the weight and stress of a centaur body...

Comment: In future, could you define things a little more clearly - "at the front of the chest" - there are two chests, the human one and the horse one. What does "front mean? - to the left of the picture or ventrally to the axis of the body (there are two bodies at different angles)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### On Average, MAYBE

From a historical & biological perspective, the answer is very possibly yes, because these people exist in your world. You don't specify how these people actually reproduce, so the answer here could be no.

Physiologically speaking, you've not provided any counterpoints to successful mating in any configuration. You don't mention equine genitalia or specify the locations of the internal reproductive arrangement, so no comment can be made on *successful mating.*

Behaviourally speaking, you don't specify anything about their cultures, beliefs, practices, etc, so even if they are physiologically able to do this, the final answer is clearly "maybe."